# Javascript Graph Google Code Dynamically Generated

Tags: javascript, static, charts

i was wondering if someone would be able to help with this function ,its from a google code line chart and what im trying to do is add values from my distanceField variable below and want to update the graph every time a new value comes in ,not sure if ive even taken the best way of dealing with the problem but any insight to the problem would be helpful 
Thank you in advance.

```
    function drawVisualization2() {
    var d2 = document.getElementById('distanceField').value;
    var i;
    var arr = new Array();
    setInterval(function() {var f1 =document.getElementById('resultField').value;},5000);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var f1 = document.getElementById('resultField').value;
    var d1 = parseInt(f1, 10);
    setTimeout(function() {
    //setInterval(function() {app.sendConnection()}, 10000);        
    //var f1 = document.getElementById('resultField').value;
    arr[i] = d1;
    }, 6000);
    }
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [ 'x', 'title' ], [ '1', arr[0] ], [ '2', arr[1] ],
    [ '3', arr[2] ], [ '4', arr[3] ], [ '5', arr[4] ],
    [ '6', arr[5] ], [ '7', arr[6] ], [ '8', arr[7] ],
    [ '9', arr[8] ], [ '10', arr[9] ],
    //['N',   1,       0.5,         1]
    ]);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document
    .getElementById('visualization2')).draw(data, {
    curveType : "function",
    width : 500,
    height : 350,
    vAxis : {
    maxValue : d2 / 2
    }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with the code block you have posted including scoping and synchronization issues - rather than try and kludge it to make it work I've rewritten it and commented as to why I've done it this way:

```
/**
 * A JS class that you can instansiate with the "new" construct 
 * on page/api load - this keeps everything self-contained and 
 * for the most part, out of the global scope.
 */
function ChartObject(){

    // internal function - neater way to grab elements
    function $(x){ return document.getElementById(x); }

    // some default data
    this.data = [['x', 'Metric Title'], ['start',0]];

    // read values from our DOM elements and add to our data array
    this.update = function(){
        var dis = $('distanceField').value.trim(),
            res = parseInt($('resultField').value, 10);
        if(!isNaN(res) && !!dis){
            this.data.push([dis, res]);
            this.draw();
        } else {
            alert('invalid entry');
        }
    };

    // redraw our graph based on our current data array
    this.draw = function(){   
        new google.visualization.LineChart($('visualization')).draw(
            google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.data), 
            {
                curveType : "function",
                width : 450,
                height : 300
            }
        );
    }

    // the following is executed once when the ChartObject is first called

    // draw the object with initial data
    this.draw();

    // add listener to button that user can click to "update" graph
    // this could be adapted to work with "onkeyup" rather than trying
    // to hack with "setTimeout"
    $('addRecord').onclick = function(){
        myChartObject.update();
    }

};
```

[**jsFiddle: working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe6xV/)

Comment: Thank you ive been working at that for a while at this stage and you have solved it in one strike ,brilliant work thank you

Comment: Just wondering actually how to get the graph to go to a 0,0 instead of starting at start like above ?

Comment: You mean like just replace `['start','0']` with `['0',0]`? ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe6xV/1/))

Comment: I mean as in the graph starts at the origin.If like in your example it puts the 0 down along the x axis ,is there a way to start at the point where the x and y axis meet.?

Comment: @Maria88 oh.  Looking at the API it doesn't look like.  The best I can suggest is to have an empty string `['',0]` to start with instead.